# Calculator HTML form using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have a little issue. That's my code and i don't know what i have made wrong. I try to complete a simple HTML form to calculate a given number in a text input html element.

```js
function rebate(){
  var rebate_a,rebate_b,total,final;

  var a = document.myform.rebatenum.value;

  if( a <= 3000 )
  {
    final = a;
  }
  else if ( (a > 3000) && (a <= 10000 ) )
  { 
    rebate_a = (a-3000) * 0.02;
    total = rebate_a;
    final = a - rebate_a;
  }
  else if ( (a > 10000) && (a <= 30000 ) )
  { 
    rebate_a = (7000 * 0.02) + (a-10000) * 0.03;
    total = rebate_a;
    final = a - rebate_a;
  }
  else if ( (a > 30000) && (a <= 40000 ) )
  { 
    rebate_a = (7000 * 0.02) + (20000 * 0.03) + (a-30000) * 0.05;
    total = rebate_a;
    final = a - rebate_a;
  }
  else if( (a >= 40000) && (a < 50000 ))
  {
    rebate_a = (7000 * 0.02) + (20000 * 0.03) + (10000 * 0.05) + (a-40000) * 0.06;
    rebate_b = 25;
    total = rebate_a + rebate_b;
    final = a - total;
  }
  else
  {
    document.myform.final.value = "20";
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
  document.myform.final.value = final;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Initial Price</td>
    <td><input name="rebatenum" type="text" size="12" onchange="rebate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Υπολογισμός" onclick="rebate();"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Final Price after rebate:</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="final" size="12"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```

You can find it also here!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/pf7Lysqt/3/

Comment: What's the question you're asking?

Comment: Check the console, rebate is not defined, which means it's not properly wrapped in the head of your fiddle

Comment: Okay, even with the function wrapped in the `head`, I still have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: thank you @SterlingArcher ...I just changed the second selection on fiddle from "OnLoad" to "No wrap-in <body>" and all worked just perfect...Thank you and sorry but i'm new to this...

Comment: please Paste your final solution as answer.

Comment: @SterlingArcher `Check the console, rebate is not defined` That's because OP had constructed the snippet wrong. I fixed it.

Comment: It would also be useful to include a description of the problem in your question.

Comment: OP, the problem with your fiddle was that `rebate` was being defined in the `onLoad` function, so it wasn't attached to the `window` object, which is what's needed to say `<elem onclick="rebate();">`. The problem with your in-question snippet was that you didn't include the JavaScript within the snippet tags.